# angular 2 checkbox checked=true is not working

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap-3

**home.ts**

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3  col-md-3 radios">
    <input [(ngModel)]="SEARCH_TYPE" [checked]="true"  type="radio" name="SEARCH_TYPE" placeholder="Starts With" title="Starts With" tab-index="" value="S" />
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3  col-md-3 radios">
    <input  [checked]=true [(ngModel)]="SEARCH_TYPE" type="radio" name="SEARCH_TYPE" placeholder="Contains" title="Contains" tab-index="" value="C" />
</div>
```

Here the second input checkbox field is by deafult checked stage,but cant see checked in radio button

Comment: Try remove the quote around `true`

Comment: @AyushGupta No luck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `[value]` to bind the value instead of `[(ngModel)]`

```
<input  [checked]="true" [value]="SEARCH_TYPE" type="radio" name="SEARCH_TYPE" placeholder="Contains" title="Contains" tab-index=""  />
```

Answer (score 1):

When you are using two-way binding as in [(ngModel)]="SEARCH-TYPE", your input's value is the initial value of this variable. You can't then also use "value=x" or "checked=true".

Either remove the properties of "checked" and "value" or remove "ngModel".